# VBA Error Check in Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code which is meant to loop through ~200 workbooks, apply a filter, and copy the filtered data back to the main workbook. How would I go about skipping any filename that throw an error and continue to the next value?

The filenames are in cells(i,7), i is my counting variable

```
For i = 7 To 46
'Define Sheet Name and open

DataBook.Sheets("Filename").Select
DealName = Cells(i, 7)
Set DealFileBook = Workbooks.Open(DealName)
```

Help greatly appreciated! Thank you

Edit1 adding full code.

Even removing the error catch is crashing my excel, does anyone have a solution on a better way to do this with less resources?

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False


Dim DealName As String
Dim DealFileBook As New Workbook
Dim DataBook As New Workbook
Dim RollBack As String

Dim i As Long


Set DataBook = ThisWorkbook


'Loop though value


'define file name
'DataBook.Sheets("Filename").Select

For i = 7 To 46


'Define Settles Sheet Name and open
On Error Resume Next
Set DealFileBook = Workbooks.Open(DealName)
On Error GoTo 0
If DealFileBook Is Nothing Then
   ' MsgBox "Error finding file name " & DealName, vbCritical
End If


'Filter for DDB and Copy
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$K$50000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="DDB"
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy

'paste into data book

DataBook.Activate
Worksheets("Data").Select
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Next i
```

Edit 3 - will post my code when done. Problem was I was not going reselecting the sheets with the filenames

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below to handle this type of error, when the filename returns an error:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set DealFileBook = Workbooks.Open(DealName)
On Error GoTo 0
If DealFileBook Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Error finding file name " & DealName, vbCritical      
End If
```

Comment: May I ask the purpose of the line `Set DealFileBook = Nothing` ? Seems it is already nothing to get into that line.

Comment: @newacc2240 it's a reflex, setting and clearing objects, you're right

Comment: This bit of code is cause excel to crash every time it hits an error

Comment: @JuniorR please add the rest of your code, since It ran on my PC correct

Comment: sure - adding now. Off top of my head, should i be close the opened workbook? also each file that is opened is ~950kb

Comment: 1) Make sure the filename saved in your cells(i,7) is the full path like `D:\documents\WorkBookNames.xlsx`. 2) The codes set an object for you, maybe a `with block` helps.

Comment: It has the full path. Could you elaborate on your second point?